# Retrieve Distinct Values From NotePad Elements

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've a notepad file that has the following format:

```
at-2017@yahoo.com
at-2017@yahoo.com
at-2018@yahoo.com
at-2018@yahoo.com
```

I require the following distinct output:

```
at-2017@yahoo.com
at-2018@yahoo.com
```

Tried the following code but it doesn't get distinct values:

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>();
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(values))
{
   line.Distinct().ToString();
   lst.Add(line);    
}
```

I know, this may seem stupid and guessing, missed something here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should read all the lines and then get the distinct lines:

```
var allLines = File.ReadLines(values);
var distinctLines = allLines.Distinct();
foreach(var distinctLine in distinctLines)
{
    Console.WriteLine(distinctLine);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Distinct()` operates on a collection of elements, so you don't need to use it inside the loop.

Try following:

```
var lst = File.ReadLines(values).Distinct();
foreach (string line in lst)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line) ;
}
```